# Calculate target partition for UUID when hash partitioning in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am using hash table partitioning in postgres v15. My partition key is a uuid. I want to be able to calculate the partition a uuid will go into so I can understand how changing my modulo will impact the distribution of tenants in the partitions.

I researched and found that I can calculate it using this formula:

```sql
select mod((uuid_hash_extended(<uuid>, 8816678312871386365)::numeric + 5305509591434766563), <modulo>)
```

Since modulo in postgres can result in a negative number we need the longer form that I found in a few places online:

```sql
select mod(mod(uuid_hash_extended(<uuid>, 8816678312871386365)::numeric + 5305509591434766563, <modulo>) + <modulo>, <modulo>)
```

I was able to confirm this initial formula by looking in the source code where I found:

- `compute_partition_hash_value`: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_15_STABLE/src/backend/partitioning/partbounds.c#L4744
- `satisfies_hash_partition`: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_15_STABLE/src/backend/partitioning/partbounds.c#L4793
- `hash_combine64`: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_15_STABLE/src/include/common/hashfn.h#L80
- `HASH_PARTITION_SEED`: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_15_STABLE/src/include/catalog/partition.h#L20

This showed that it used a hash seed of `0x7A5B22367996DCFD` (`8816678312871386365` in decimal) in the hash function and that it always called `hash_combine64` even if there was only one value. `hash_combine64` adds the hash to random data of  `0x49a0f4dd15e5a8e3` (`5305509591434766563` in decimal) and the rest can be ignored if we only have one column since 0 is passed in for `a`.

In practice this seemed to work fine till I found a partition that included values that generated a different remainder than the hash they were in.

Here is an example:

```sql
create table party (
  id uuid not null primary key
) partition by hash(id);

create table party_0 partition of party for values with (modulus 12, remainder 0);
create table party_1 partition of party for values with (modulus 12, remainder 1);
create table party_2 partition of party for values with (modulus 12, remainder 2);
create table party_3 partition of party for values with (modulus 12, remainder 3);
create table party_4 partition of party for values with (modulus 12, remainder 4);
create table party_5 partition of party for values with (modulus 12, remainder 5);
create table party_6 partition of party for values with (modulus 12, remainder 6);
create table party_7 partition of party for values with (modulus 12, remainder 7);
create table party_8 partition of party for values with (modulus 12, remainder 8);
create table party_9 partition of party for values with (modulus 12, remainder 9);
create table party_10 partition of party for values with (modulus 12, remainder 10);
create table party_11 partition of party for values with (modulus 12, remainder 11);

insert into party (id)
values
('fee0d5e9-e3c7-4024-9530-bbb91aa2a2b7'),
('f311dfb5-b878-49d0-9e27-f08c568922c0'),
('cea7891f-ed6d-449d-93ba-62eb9734b212'),
('9e3643a8-6828-409a-a0f5-a6e78c94e361');

select id,
  tableoid::regclass::text as "table",
  satisfies_hash_partition('party'::regclass, 12, 11, id),
  mod(mod(uuid_hash_extended(id, 8816678312871386365)::numeric + 5305509591434766563, 12) + 12, 12) as "remainder"
from party;
```

The last query spit out this result:

```
id                                  |table   |satisfies_hash_partition|remainder|
------------------------------------+--------+------------------------+---------+
fee0d5e9-e3c7-4024-9530-bbb91aa2a2b7|party_11|true                    |       11|
f311dfb5-b878-49d0-9e27-f08c568922c0|party_11|true                    |        7|
cea7891f-ed6d-449d-93ba-62eb9734b212|party_11|true                    |        7|
9e3643a8-6828-409a-a0f5-a6e78c94e361|party_11|true                    |       11|
```

**Why does the remainder formula result in 7 for some of the partitions that are clearly part of the 11 remainder group?**

I think it has something to do with how I handle negative results from the modulo operation since the 7 appears for those that would generate -5 on the first version of the formula above. In `satisfies_hash_partition` I see it uses `PG_RETURN_BOOL(rowHash % modulus == remainder);` and it does not appear to have any special handling for the negative case.

### Edit #1

It has been many years since I have worked in C but I think what I am missing was in this line:
https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_15_STABLE/src/backend/partitioning/partbounds.c#L4769

```c
rowHash = hash_combine64(rowHash, DatumGetUInt64(hash));
```

Specifically the `DatumGetUInt64` which I believe converts the value to an unsigned 64 bit integer. My understanding of how to convert a signed integer to an unsigned is to add it to the max uint 64 value (2^64 = 18446744073709551616).

So I would change my formula to:

```sql
select (18446744073709551616 + uuid_hash_extended(<uuid>, 8816678312871386365) + 5305509591434766563) % <modulo>
```

Now this works for negative results from `uuid_hash_extended` in my example above but not for positive ones. So we need to add some conditionals like so:
With this new formula I get the following results:

```sql
(case   
    when uuid_hash_extended(<uuid>, 8816678312871386365) < 0
    then 18446744073709551616 + uuid_hash_extended(<uuid>, 8816678312871386365)
    else uuid_hash_extended(<uuid>, 8816678312871386365)
  end + 5305509591434766563) % <modulo>
```

In the end, this worked for the uuids in my above example but I found others it didn't for. For example `06abcb5f-6cd2-4532-8423-ec6625cd2282` is in the partition with the remainder 11 but my formula produces a 3 :(

### Edit #2

I discovered that the formula works fine for any modulo value that is a power of 2 (e.g. 2, 4, 8, 16, ...). It fails to work for any negative hash value if the modulo is not a power of 2. It still exhibits a pattern for which I have been unable to define a formula but do have a method.

The method follows this sequence:

1. Create a partitioned table with `X` partitions (e.g. Mod X).
2. Insert a bunch of random UUIDs
3. Run this function to view the remainders that our formula calculates for each table:

```sql
select distinct 
  substring(tableoid::regclass::text, 'party_(\d+)')::numeric as remainder,
  tableoid::regclass::text as "table",
  mod(uuid_hash_extended(id, 8816678312871386365)::numeric + 5305509591434766563, <X>) as "remainder",
  mod(
    mod(uuid_hash_extended(id, 8816678312871386365)::numeric + 5305509591434766563, <X>) + <X>
  , <X>) as "adj_remainder"
from "party"
order by 1, 2
```

For X=7, we get the following results:

```
remainder|table  |remainder|adj_remainder|
---------+-------+---------+-------------+
        0|party_0|        0|            0|
        0|party_0|       -2|            5|
        1|party_1|        1|            1|
        1|party_1|       -1|            6|
        2|party_2|        0|            0|
        2|party_2|        2|            2|
        3|party_3|       -6|            1|
        3|party_3|        3|            3|
        4|party_4|       -5|            2|
        4|party_4|        4|            4|
        5|party_5|       -4|            3|
        5|party_5|        5|            5|
        6|party_6|        6|            6|
        6|party_6|       -3|            4|
```

4. Add the absolute value of both `remainder` values for a given table (e.g. for `party_0` 2 + 0 = 2). We will refer to this value as `Y`.
5. Use the following query to accurately get the target partition:

```sql
select
  distinct 
  substring(tableoid::regclass::text, 'party_(\d+)')::numeric as remainder,
  tableoid::regclass::text as "table",
case   
    when (uuid_hash_extended(id, 8816678312871386365)::numeric + 5305509591434766563) > 0
      then (uuid_hash_extended(id, 8816678312871386365)::numeric + 5305509591434766563) % <X>
    else ((uuid_hash_extended(id, 8816678312871386365)::numeric + 5305509591434766563) % <X> + (<X> + <Y>)) % <X>
  end as "remainder"
from "party"
order by 1, 2
```

Let me break down this formula a bit:

```sql
-- If the hash is not negative, then do the normal operation.
-- This is important because the "negative" value for partition
-- number `Y` will be 0 which can't be distinguished from 
-- the "positive" value for partition 0 which is also 0.
-- So you need to look at the original hash value to see if it is
-- negative rather than just at the result of the modulo.
    when (uuid_hash_extended(id, 8816678312871386365)::numeric + 5305509591434766563) > 0
      then (uuid_hash_extended(id, 8816678312871386365)::numeric + 5305509591434766563) % <X>
-- For remainders less than <Y> you can actually just use <Y>
-- instead of <X> + <Y> but the formula is shorter this way
-- and works for remainders < and > <Y> because of the % <X>
    else ((uuid_hash_extended(id, 8816678312871386365)::numeric + 5305509591434766563) % <X> + (<X> + <Y>)) % <X>
```

This method produces the correct remainder each time. The problem is that I would like a way to calculate `Y` without having to insert data into an actually table to figure it out. I want a formula to solve for `Y` given any `X`.

The following are some values for `X` and `Y` that I derived:

```
X   Y
38  36
37  12
36  16
35  16
34  18
33  16
32  32
24  16
20  16
16  16
12  4
8   8
7   2
```

Comment: Hi @bygrace,
i see in source code that hash_combine64 combine an initial 0 value with UINT64 of hash calculated for your key value.
The following formula is used in this calculation: `a ^= b + UINT64CONST(0x49a0f4dd15e5a8e3) + (a << 54) + (a >> 7);`
What about `(a << 54) + (a >> 7);`? did you include this part in your query?

Comment: @GlaucoCucchiar that part is only relevant if you are using composite keys. For single column keys `a` is always 0 so it wont have an impact since bit shifting 0 will result in 0